# IoTivity vs AllJoyn - what is the difference?

Tags: frameworks, protocols, iot, alljoyn, iotivity

Open Interconnect Consortium has just released [IoTivity](https://www.iotivity.org/), an open source framework for IoT, similar to AllSeen Alliance's [AllJoyn](https://allseenalliance.org/) framework. What are the differences between them, apart from IoTivity being based on CoAP and AllJoyn based on D-Bus? Are they interoperable?

Comment: Regarding interoperability, you might want to read about IoTivity's [iotivity-alljoyn-bridge](https://github.com/iotivity/iotivity-alljoyn-bridge) project.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

*This is a community wiki, so please expand it if you can.*

---

### Architecture

#### IoTivity

IoTivity provides 4 basic components:

- Discovery
- Data transmission
- Data Management
- Device management

[image: Source: iotivity.org]

#### AllJoyn

AllJoyn provides the following components:

- App Code
- Service Frameworks Libraries
- Core Library
- Router

It also provides the Thin variant without the Router.

[image: Source: itessays.com]

### Protocols

#### IoTivity

IoTivity will be using multiple protocols, but for now it uses CoAP. IT also has a MQTT plugin.

[image: Source: iotivity.org]

#### AllJoyn

AllJoyn provides its own [bus](https://allseenalliance.org/developer-resources/forum/developers/difference-d-bus) based on D-Bus Wire protocol. AllJoyn Gateway Agent will have connectors for REST, MQTT, XMPP and TR-069.

[image: Source: allseenalliance.org]

### Supported platforms

#### IoTivity

IoTivity currently supports:

- Android
- Arduino
- darwin/iOS
- Linux
- Tizen
- Windows
- Yocto

#### AllJoyn

AllJoyn currently supports:

- Android
- Arduino
- iOS
- Linux
- OS X
- Windows

Answer (score 10):

As explained at OpenIoT 2016 :

[image: OpenIoT]

Full presentation at :

http://events.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/slides/OpenIoT%20Summit%20Greg%20Burns.pdf

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=siT2TPnTRHY&list=PLq2bxbH0KVGmtGRUQ4G7RfxsDeGtc9Yxz

Answer (score 3):

When it comes to supported transports, AllJoyn now supports more. It supports IP-related physical layers like WiFi, WiFi-Direct, Ethernet and Powerline. Also, it can support bluetooth with their gateway agent. Other radios such as Bluetooth LE, 6LowPan, ZigBee or Z–Wave are encouraged to be added.

The following is a snapshot from the QA session in Allseen official website.

[image: A snapshot from the QA session in AllJoyn official website]

Reference: https://allseenalliance.org/alliance/faq#n142

Answer (score 1):

One additional difference between these frameworks is how they treat Intellectual Property rights. AllSeen require from members not to sue other vendors which used AllJoyn for their product (Patent Non-Assertion Pledge).

Answer (score 0):

Iotivity is easy to use, it provides C and C++ sdk for developing application on constrained devices. Quite easy to use for a basic application, provides GET,PUT ,POST and Observe functionality. Compared to Alljoyn it is faster and easier to develop apps on it.

Answer (score -6):

Theyre completely different frameworks made by different companies that are both trying to achieve the same (or similar) thing. Its like comparing iOS to android.

They are not interoperable.

Comment: iOS and Android are comparable. I am asking for the differences when performing similar functions.